# API curl in php - Authorize curl in header

Tags: php, curl

I use this php example to get details about listing via API and it works.

```php
$url = "http://api.example.com/apiListing/get";

$input = array (
    userId => xxx, // authentication userId
    loginToken => 'xxx', // authentication loginToken
    "id" => "11011947"
);

$data_string = http_build_query($input);

$url = "$url?$data_string";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
```

I have to change site authorization to **Site authorized only by userId and Token in HEADER**

This is the example from API specification:

```
curl --request POST -H "Content-Type=multipart/form-data" -H "SiteAuth:<userId>:<Token>" "https://api.example.com/site/listing?id=<listingId>"
```

How to set login in HEADER in PHP curl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the equivelant to your command example:

```
<?php
$userId = "<userId>";
$token = "<Token>";
$listingId = "<listingId>";

$url = "https://api.example.com/site/listing?id=" . urlencode($listingId);

$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

$headers = array(
    "Content-Type: multipart/form-data",
    "SiteAuth: $userId:$token"
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

if ($response === false) {
    echo "Error: " . curl_error($ch);
} else {
    echo "Response: " . $response;
}

curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but Message Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found

Comment: Are you uploading files?  Your code and the example don't show any work toward an upload.